# how to actually install PHP etc on a windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, installation

We're just purchasing a dedicated windows 2003 server (in fact I think it's a VPS)

How do we actually go about *installing* software on to it? Simply searching for "installing PHP5 on windows server" just produces material about installing it as if one had access to the computer with a keyboard and mouse.

Am I being thick? I've had experience managing a linux server before but that had everything pre-configured and we accessed it via Web Hosting Manager.

I don't get the actual concept of connecting to a remote PC and...downloading files?

If there's any good books available please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't get the concept of remotely connecting to a server and downloading files on it, [this is probably not an appropriate site for you, being for professional Systems Administrators.](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of remote access. With windows, it's mostly either remote desktop, or in some special, rare cases, a special access console (software) to access the virtual machine (something like remote desktop, but the windows on the other side thinks it's a local display/io-device).

After getting that, you can follow the tutorials you've found.